# addSubview in Cocoa framework

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a regular DocumentView class in a Window.  I have the following code once a user presses a button:

```
- (void)handleButtonPress:(NSNotification *)note{
  // draw new graph view
  EDGraphView *graph = [[EDGraphView alloc] init];
  [self addSubview:graph];
  [self setNeedsDisplay:TRUE];

  NSLog(@"Button was pressed");
}
```

This gets called correctly because I get the output "Button was pressed" every time I click on the button.  In addition to that the *drawRect* method below of the view gets called as well.

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
  NSRect bounds = [self bounds];
  [[NSColor whiteColor] set];
  [NSBezierPath fillRect:bounds];

  for(EDGraphView *graph in [self subviews]){
    [graph setNeedsDisplay:TRUE];
    NSLog("calling set needs display on graph object!");
  }
}
```

However when I go in the EDGraphView class and edit the *drawRect* method to look like the following

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
  NSLog(@"redrawing graph view.");
}
```

It never gets called!  I must be missing something about the whole *setNeedsDisplay* and *drawRect* process.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it...I needed to make the following init call on my subview:

```
EDGraphView *graph = [[EDGraphView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
```

Now it calls the drawRect method!

Answer (score 0):

hi Normaly you don't call setneeddisplay into a drawrect.

have you tried  (with the super)? :

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    NSRect bounds = [self bounds];
   [[NSColor whiteColor] set];
   [NSBezierPath fillRect:bounds];
   [super drawRect:rect];

}
```

Comment: Thanks divot but no luck.  The reason I'm calling setNeedDisplay on the subviews is to let them know that they need to call drawRect as well.

Comment: normally you do not need to call setNeedDisplay on subviews into drawrect, if the parent view needs to update all its  subviews are redrawned. As long you specialized a drawRect it's called.